# how to rewrite only if there're more than 2 characters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've a problem with the apache htaccess rewrite... this is my urls:

1. [www.test.org/category/subcategory](http://www.test.org/category/subcategory)
2. [www.test.org/en/category/subcategory](http://www.test.org/en/category/subcategory)
3. [www.test.org/en/category/subcategory/article1](http://www.test.org/en/category/subcategory/article1)

to rewrite 1) i use this rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]*)/([a-z0-9-_]*)$ /index.php?detMod=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

but if i've the language folder (en) how i can do?! help

Comment: You can use the quantifier `{2}` to demand exactly two characters out of a character class.

Comment: What is target rewrite URL for `http://www.test.org/en/category/subcategory/article1` ?